# How can I keep Safari from re-opening my tabs from my last session?

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

When I re-open Safari on my Mac Mini, it keeps opening the same tabs that were open before it was quit (or before the Mac OS X was switched off). The result is that it takes too much time to be operative, especially when I restart my Mac.

In the preference panel, the "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps" option is already disabled, but Safari keeps opening the tabs open in the last session. I checked also in my MacBook, which is running Mac OS X 10.7.2, and that option doesn't change the Safari's behavior I describe in this question.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to force it not to open all the tabs? I looked at its preferences, but I have not found anything that could help me. Is there any other way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quit Safari with ⌥⌘Q and run this in the Terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Now Safari opens faster, and I can access the site I want without to wait at least 2 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: You could also hold shift while opening Safari (it doesn't work when apps are opened with Spotlight or Alfred though) or uncheck *Restore windows when quitting and reopening apps* in the General preference pane.

Comment: What is "the Terminal" ?
You guys said type this into the terminal.
What do you mean by Terminal?
What is The Terminal?

Comment: Macintosh HD/Applications/Utilities/[Terminal.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X))

Comment: You can also keep your fingers pressed on CMD + W until all tabs are closed before quitting. Safari will then try to reopen tabs but there won't be any to reopen.

Comment: @jaepage The difference is that in the case of my answer you can still save state when quitting if you explicitly say so (by keyboard shortcut or via the menu), while in case of the other answer you can't.

Comment: Does not work with Safari 10.1.

Comment: The other answer works in Safari 12.0 and tabs from the previous session can be restored with History > Reopen All Windows From Last Session.

Answer (score 11):

This behavior is the **resume** feature.

### Disable using Terminal

If you only want to disable resume for safari, type this in the terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.safari ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES
```

If you want to set the resume feature again, simply write NO using the same syntax.

### Disable using [**TinkerTool**](http://bresink.de/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php5)

This application gives you access to additional preference settings and allows to activate hidden features in the operating system.

[image]

Comment: TinkerTool is basically doing all those commands for you; it's doing the same job as the terminal command, just with a UI

Comment: I can't believe Apple is hiding this behaviour. Well I can believe it and hate it. Thanks for the right command.