# Restoring a previous "session" (with various open tabs) in Safari—macOS Sierra

Tags: safari, macos

How do I **restore** a previous **Safari** session during which I quit the application while numerous tabs were open?

There is NOTHING in Preferences that I could find where this could be made possible.

I looked in Preferences > General ...

NO "Close windows when quitting an app" option as one Answer suggested.

Nothing.

macOS 10.12.6 Sierra

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34284/how-can-i-keep-safari-from-re-opening-my-tabs-from-my-last-session?rq=1 See if using true in accepted answer or  NO  in the other answer works

Comment: Also in the History menu look for "Recently Closed >" "Reopen last closed tab" and "Reopen all windows from last session."

Answer (score 3):

**Open the Last Closed Tab in Safari on the Mac**

Safari lets you undo your action of closing a tab--as long as you act promptly. If you close a tab by mistake and then open a new tab, you won't be able to restore the closed tab with the shortcut below, because the undo feature only works on your last action.

[image]

**Reopen Closed Windows in Safari on the Mac**

You can also reopen a Safari window with the tabs you had open even days after closing the window or quitting Safari.

If you have more than one Safari window open and close one by mistake, go to the History menu and select "*Reopen Last Closed Window.*"

[image]

If you quit Safari and want to restart it with all of the tabs you had open last time, go to the History menu and select Reopen All Windows from Last Session.

[image]